# How to operate with binary numbers as if they were a string

Tags: matlab, vector, binary

What I have to do is: assume x1= 0 0 1 and x2 = 0 1 0, given a number L length give to switch positions, let's say L=2 (it changes randomly), I'd have to switch de numbers like this:

x1=  0 0 1; x1'= 0 0 0
x2 = 0 1 0; x2'= 0 1 1

What I've done so far. Each binary number is a code that has a value. So I said, ok, I can make a vector, the position of the vector is the code, and inside the value, of course.

Now, when I need to access this string or bits or code, not sure how to call it, I've been looking and I've found this two functions(that I didn't know of before):

**dec2bin and de2bi**. I believe the second one would be the most useful as it creates a vector. And so I guess I would have the vector from position 1 to L and from L+1 to N of both x1 and x2, and somehow switch both of those (right now I'm thinking of using a 3rd vector so it'd go: x1 to xcopy, x2 to x1, x1 to x2 (the proper halfs, not all of the vector of course). But I'm sure there are better ways of doing this particular switching, and the whole thing.

Could someone tell me of a better or more useful way of approaching this problem? In other languages I feel it'd be more natural, like using a Map or even a struct I guess, this is the idea I came with for matlab but it feels... unnecesary or redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at bitset() in Matlab's help. This function allows you to change individual bit values in a word.

Comment: Do you know how could I go with the coding part? Like, If a number is 4 and another number "converted to binary" is 15, I'm going to need 4 bits but de2bi is just going to give me 2: 1 1, so right now your answer is indeed going to help me (thanks for that!) but I'm missing something else.

Comment: aalright I just answered my own question with my own function. de2bi lets you specify number of columns like: de2bi([3 9],5) for example would have 5 columns, it adds 0's, so I think between that and your answer I might get something done, Thanks!